# How to implement outofbound on switch-case

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, web-services

I have the next error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 I hope somebody can help me to resolve this. I think I need to check for String not to be null, but I don't know how to implement it in the next code.

This is my code:

```
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:763)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at it.nad.cartellecliniche.PatientPageActivity$1.onItemClick(PatientPageActivity.java:224)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at it.nad.cartellecliniche.PatientPageActivity.fillVisiteList(PatientPageActivity.java:253)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at it.nad.cartellecliniche.PatientPageActivity.onTaskComplete(PatientPageActivity.java:593)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at it.nad.cartellecliniche.asynctask.SearchVisiteTask.onPostExecute(SearchVisiteTask.java:263)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at it.nad.cartellecliniche.asynctask.SearchVisiteTask.onPostExecute(SearchVisiteTask.java:1)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-25 15:22:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)



    public void onTaskComplete(Object[] output) {
        super.onTaskComplete(output);
        Integer resultOperation = (Integer) output[0];
         if (output != null && resultOperation != 500) {
            String typeTask = (String) output[1];
                if (typeTask.equals("SearchListVisite")) {
                    switch (resultOperation) {

                        case 200: {
                        Visita[] visite_current_patient = (Visita[]) output[2];                         
                        fillVisiteList(visite_current_patient);
                        break;
                    }   
                        case 204: {
                        Visita[] visitaEmpty = createVisteListEmpty();
                        fillVisiteList(visitaEmpty);
                        break;
                    }
                    }
            }
        } else {
            CharSequence testo = "Errore!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, testo, duration);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Comment: post the stacktrace please

Comment: You have an empty object "output" `Integer resultOperation = (Integer) output[0];` You should check for the length of an array **before** using its elements. There is **NO ELEMENT 0**, if the length is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution whith a different If statement:

if(visite_current_patient.length < 2)

```
  public void onTaskComplete(Object[] output) {
    super.onTaskComplete(output);   
    Integer resultOperation = (Integer) output[0];

    if (output != null && resultOperation != 500) {
        String typeTask = (String) output[1];
        if (typeTask.equals("SearchListVisite")) {
            switch (resultOperation) {
            case 200:
                Visita[] visite_current_patient = (Visita[]) output[2];
                if(visite_current_patient.length < 2) {
                    visite_current_patient = createVisteListEmpty();
                }
                fillVisiteList(visite_current_patient);
                break;
            case 204:
                Visita[] visitaEmpty = createVisteListEmpty();
                fillVisiteList(visitaEmpty);
                break;
            }

    } else {
        CharSequence testo = "Errore!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, testo, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        onBackPressed();
    }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line:

```
Integer resultOperation = (Integer) output[0];
```

inside the if statement to prevent `NullPointerException`. And add the condition:

```
output.length >= 3
```

I did a refactoring and hope this I did not broke anything. But you have not provided all types to make it compile in my IDE:

```
public void onTaskComplete(Object[] output) {
    super.onTaskComplete(output);
    if (output != null && output.length >= 3) {
        Integer resultOperation = (Integer) output[0];
        String typeTask = (String) output[1];
        if (typeTask.equals("SearchListVisite")) {
            switch (resultOperation) {
            case 200:
                Visita[] visite_current_patient = (Visita[]) output[2];                         
                fillVisiteList(visite_current_patient);
                break;
            case 204:
                Visita[] visitaEmpty = createVisteListEmpty();
                fillVisiteList(visitaEmpty);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        CharSequence testo = "Errore!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, testo, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: except in this case resultOperation is not defined.